# How to make the text case insensitive?

Tags: c#

Kindly suggest me a way to make the text case insensitive. The textbox input need to be compared irrespective of whatever case the user use

**Example**:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Name")
{
   label1.Content = "This is" + textBox1.Text;
}
```

If the `textBox1` input is Name/ NAME/ name, the label should display the corresponding value.

Comment: Use `String.ToUpper()`

Comment: Do not use String.ToUpper(). Use the appropriate Equals Method instead.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster why? what is the reason?

Comment: First, you want to express equality. Nothing does this better than a .Equals(). The == might, but not when you convert one argument to uppercase.
Second, you wrote only `.ToUpper()` at first. That ignores the culture and may lead to language issues later on. What if my culture defines an uppercase "m" as "ᴍ" and makes "M" a different letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing strings you really want to use the `.Equals` method

```
textBox1.Text.Equals("Name", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

The second parameter allows you to specify a `StringComparison`. In this example it tells it to ***ignore the case***.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for **[StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

```
if(string.Equals(textBox1.Text, "Name", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

You may also try to look at

[System.Collections.CaseInsensitiveComparer](http://System.Collections.CaseInsensitiveComparer)

Comment: Thanks to all for your prompt responses but it seems that I am missing something as when I tried implementing your instructions, it shows an error: "The name 'StringComparision' does not exist in the current context". Kindly advise!

Comment: Make sure you have a `using System;` statement at the top of your file, although why you *wouldn't* is suspect.

Comment: Yes I tried with your suggestion but it still returns the same error

Comment: @user3172531:- Although I am not sure why it is not working for you as it looks good at my side. Anyways you may try like this too:- `string.CompareInfo.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, "Name", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: That too is not working! Anyways thank you so much for your kind effort!

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use [ToUpper](http://www.dotnetperls.com/toupper) or [`ToUpperInvariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (textBox1.Text.ToUpper() == "NAME")
```

if you need to uppercase using the casing rules of the invariant culture

```
if (textBox1.Text.ToUpperInvariant() == "NAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Can you please try the following:**

```
   if(textBox1.text.Equals("value",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks to all for your prompt responses but it seems that I am missing something as when I tried implementing your instructions, it shows an error: "The name 'StringComparision' does not exist in the current context". Kindly advise!

Comment: Resolve item is not showing in the menu. I have declared using System; statement and also System.Text; and System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: @user3172531...Go to object browser , in mscorlib, check whether you have StringComparer Class..

Comment: Your suggestion works! Something else would have went wrong when I tried this yesterday. Thanks, Have a great day!

Comment: @user3172531...You are welcome :) and also i suggest you to change your user name by editing your profile so that it will be easy to refer to you rather than akward looking userid that is being auto generated by the SO system

Comment: Thanks! Changed my username as advised!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
if(textBox1.Text.Equals("Name",StringComparision.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
  label1.Content = "This is" + textBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if (textBox1.Text.ToLowerInvariant() == "Name".ToLowerInvariant())
     label1.Content = "This is" + textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as suggested but its not giving the desired output.

Comment: And which output is giving? :P

Answer (score -1):

You can instantiate a comparer and reuse it throughout your code.

This Insensitive class provides a thorough set of insensitive comparison methods:

```
public static class Insensitive
{
    private static IComparer m_Comparer = CaseInsensitiveComparer.Default;

    public static IComparer Comparer
    {
        get{ return m_Comparer; }
    }

    public static int Compare( string a, string b )
    {
        return m_Comparer.Compare( a, b );
    }

    public static bool Equals( string a, string b )
    {
        if ( a == null && b == null )
            return true;
        else if ( a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length )
            return false;

        return ( m_Comparer.Compare( a, b ) == 0 );
    }

    public static bool StartsWith( string a, string b )
    {
        if ( a == null || b == null || a.Length < b.Length )
            return false;

        return ( m_Comparer.Compare( a.Substring( 0, b.Length ), b ) == 0 );
    }

    public static bool EndsWith( string a, string b )
    {
        if ( a == null || b == null || a.Length < b.Length )
            return false;

        return ( m_Comparer.Compare( a.Substring( a.Length - b.Length ), b ) == 0 );
    }

    public static bool Contains( string a, string b )
    {
        if ( a == null || b == null || a.Length < b.Length )
            return false;

        a = a.ToLower();
        b = b.ToLower();

        return ( a.IndexOf( b ) >= 0 );
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/runuo/runuo/blob/master/Server/Insensitive.cs

Comment: Please prefer inline content over link-only answers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will revise the answer when I have a spare moment.